# What iPhone / iPad apps do you use for gaming?

Tags: tools, mobile

What iPhone / iPad applications do you use for your gaming?  One per answer, please, and vote up ones you have used and like.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a poll with no specific answer or problem to solve.

Answer (score 15):

**GoodReader** is the home app for many of my game-book PDFs. It loads quickly, even with art-heavy works, and the bookmarking function is really useful.

Comment: As of 5th Dec 2013: Just a quick note, if you are using an older iPad, the new iOS-7 doesn't work well with Goodreader. There's an update coming in Dec (so says the developer on his FB page), but no idea if you have to re-buy it like PDF Expert 5.

Answer (score 15):

Dropbox.  I use it to sync my notes, books, and character sheets.  For larger books, you can even send files from Dropbox straight to GoodReader if the Dropbox PDF viewer is too slow for your liking.

Answer (score 11):

I just used [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) at game night for the first time last week and was very impressed.

Using their desktop app on my home computer, I created separate notes for

- encounters (containing maps, monsters (including custom ones), and verbiage)
- Important NPCs
- The details of an artifact I was handing out
- The full text to a poem full of clues that the party would discover (to be emailed out when they found it)
- Images to be shown to the players
- An encounter flow diagram

Evernote took it all and slurped it up into its cloud.  During the day I updated and tweaked things on my Android phone, iPad and work computer.  When game time finally arrived, it was all ready to go on my iPad.  It was the best combination of prepared and organized that I've ever felt.  Best of all, the app is free up to 40Meg of upload per month.  Unless you are uploading high res images that will be plenty to run a game on.

Answer (score 7):

iPlay4e.com, which has an iPhone optimised website for 4e character sheets. Fantastic tool.

Just go to http://iplay4e.com on your phone.

Comment: iPlay4e also makes havey use of inCombat letting you export monster files from the monsterbuilder and load them into iplay4e and save them as encounter files.

Answer (score 5):

Google Docs is a fantastic reference that is usually iphone renderable. I have my players maintain their character sheets and a [time log](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1vKLq9NmO8qVj-TqfgxmDixo2KVORRnYArzM5eMNRm_A) that are accesable from iphone or laptop at the table.

Answer (score 4):

**Dicenomicon** is a heavy-duty programmable dice emulator. It has the most extensive set of custom features that I've seen in such an app.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Mach Dice](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/mach-dice/id287598627?mt=8). Mach just recently added support for Fudge dice during the great Fudge dice shortage of 2010!

Answer (score 4):

I have recently started using [Notability](http://www.gingerlabs.com/cont/notability.php) for my games and prep.

I can type, write, draw, map, annotate, highlight, and record. I can import images and PDFs and web clips.

It can auto sync to a variety of cloud storage services including Dropbox and google drive, in your choice of several formats.

It's super-useful and for $0.99, it's a steal!

Comment: Notability is also very stylus friendly, and I find handwriting more convenient when dealing with all the made up nonsense words and proper nouns we use in RPGs that the iOS keyboard tries to autocorrect away.

Answer (score 2):

**GMToolKit** provides a basic die roller, a name generator, a room description generator, and a place-name generator based on random root-words translated into a variety of language "inspirations".

The place-name generator is by far the most interesting feature. It first generates a random combination of English words that would be suitable for a place (such as "pine meadow"), then it gives four variations built from a rough translation into German, Gaelic, Latin, and Old English (such as "Kieferwiese", "Cranncluain", "Agerpinus", and "Beamfeld" for "pine meadow".)

The room description generator is alright, but seems to have a limited variety of "pieces" to put together into a fixed skeleton. It's enough to give some inspiration and little bits of dungeon-dressing, but used too often it will get repetitive. I wouldn't use it verbatim.

The name generator is a little more random that I'd like, but is very quick. It might take more than a few taps, but eventually a name will jump out as being good-sounding.

The die roller is pretty basic. Enough for a single die throw of one or more dice of the same size, but nothing to compete with Dicenomicon or Mach Dice.

Comment: I just checked this out -- the bit where it generates random rolls every X seconds (so that your players don't know when you're making a roll) is awesome for that style of campaign. No more telegraphing your Notice/Perception checks...

Answer (score 2):

[**Ambiance**](http://ambiance.urbanapps.com/) has a huge library of free soundscapes, such as spooky graveyards, sci-fi laboratories, etc. I haven't used it in a gaming setting yet, personally, but you can easily plug it into a stereo or dock and use it to generate atmosphere for your game. It also supports iOS 4 multitasking, so the sounds continue to play even when you exit the app to do something else.

Comment: Just to clarify, the app isn't free. Still pretty cool.

Comment: True. It was recently free for a few days, which is when I picked it up. There's also a lite version available, which I believe limits you to having only 5 soundscapes downloaded at any one time.

Answer (score 2):

[**Simplenote**](http://simplenoteapp.com/) is a free, light, bare-bones note-taking app, that syncs between your iPhone, the Simplenote website, various desktop apps, and other devices. Notes can be edited, tagged, searched, and restored to previous versions. While not specifically geared towards gaming, it's useful for pretty much everything, and serves as a much lighter version of Evernote.

Answer (score 2):

I use [i4e](http://cordax.net/i4e/) (nonfree, but cheap) and I'm absolutely delighted with it. It's local to the phone (but with a web-based importer) which means I don't have any lookup time when I'm using my powers. Furthermore, customizable descriptions are remarkably handy.

Answer (score 1):

Pip is a good, simple dice roller with nice graphics and physics and no other frills.  [Here's a review](http://diceofdoom.com/blog/2008/12/iphone-rpg-dice-roller-pip-reminds-us-simple-is-often-better/).

Answer (score 1):

RPGplane is an iOS app featuring 15 maps (some bigger then 6000 pixels) and the ability to set fog density, field of view, and grid size with a finger swipe.

It allows for unlimited checkers with individual size, colour, text, number, and field of view. Avatars and tokens are planned for a later release. There are objects such as treasure chest, coins, and weapons to represent rewards.

The next update will introduce dice rolling and the ability to load RPGplane maps pre-populated with monsters and objects by the publisher, for instant scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Tap Counter](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tap-counter/id313084030?mt=8) for tracking Counts in Hackmaster. Simple to use and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

[Feudz Dice](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/feudz-dice-roller/id382386667?mt=8).  I haven't personally used it yet, but I've toyed with the app.  I got it based on a friend's recommendation.  He showed me how you can set up all kinds of crazy things.  You can create a group of dicerolls (for example multiple characters).  He set up his current character as a group and then you go in and he had all the various combat rolls he has all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

If I need a simple counter for tallys and such, I use [Score](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/score/id288350288?mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

I really like to use sounds, so I have an app called [Resounder](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/resounder-unlimited-soundboards/id306426146?mt=8) that lets me have a pretty huge  Soundboard library. It actually lets you import your own sounds (wav, aiff, mp3). Very useful for laugh tracks, drum rolls, and failure sounds (waaa-waaaa).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [OmniOutliner](http://www.omnigroup.com/omnioutliner) as a campaign management tool for years, and recently I've been using the iPad version ($29.99) more than the Mac version. One OmniOutliner file can hold all the notes for an entire campaign, and because it's an outliner, you only see what you need to see for a given session, encounter, etc. While it does not sync to Dropbox, OmniGroup provides a free sync service called OmniPresence which works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

For our VTM 20 campaigns I created a webbased charactersheet tool in php and mysql. Is has the ability to create accounts for players who can all create very detailed public PC sheets and hidden NPC sheets. You can make and save notes in each sheet and send the to a list of fallen when they die. Id be happy to share it, pm me if interested.

Comment: This isn't a forum—there's no such thing as PMs here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, ha sorry about that, wasn't thinking... Not going to post my email so send me a message though wwww.bobhamers.nl if you're interested.

Answer (score -4):

A custom web app I wrote to do Savage Worlds character sheets and dice rolling. iOS devices do awesomely with HTML5/javascript stuff (except sound playing, which is a giant pain in the ass) and a good framework like jQuery Mobile makes writing your own snazzy thing pretty easy.

Comment: -1 As it is, this post seems a bit localized to be of use, especially since others can't benefit from it (no links, etc).